# Python TypeError - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, api, lambda, philips-hue

I have a Lambda function that is designed to turn ON/OFF my Philip HUE lightbulbs. I am able to execute the python script & it runs (error-free) on my local machine. However, when I trigger the Lambda function (using an IoT Button) I get the following error message.

```
[ERROR] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in lambda_handler
    if data["state"]["on"] == False:
```

Does anyone have any ideas/insight? Here is the full Python script:

```
import requests,json

bridgeIP = "ip_here"
userID = "userID_here"
lightID = "4" #Represents the ID assigned to lightbulb, in the living room.

def lambda_handler(lightID, lambda_context):
    url = f"http://{bridgeIP}/api/{userID}/lights/{lightID}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    if data["state"]["on"] == False:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":True}))
    elif data["state"]["on"] == True:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":False}))

lambda_handler(lightID, 4)
```

The last line in my script calls the lambda_handler() function. I'm told that I do not need this line because my Lambda calls the function when the Lambda Function is triggered. However I (believe) that I do need to manually call the function, when executing the script on my local machine.

Comment: It looks like `data` or `data["state"]` is value that allows indexing with a string (like a dictionary) when you run it locally, but it is a list (which does not allow indexing with a string) when you run it on the device. Possibly you're not getting the data from the exact same source when testing?

Comment: If this helps, this is the value of the "data" variable -->
{'state': {'on': False, 'bri': 1, 'hue': 13248, 'sat': 5, 'reachable': True}, 'swupdate': {'state': 'noupdates', 'lastinstall': '2019-07-26T19:09:54'}, 'manufacturername': 'Philips'}
This is the value of data["state"] -->
{'on': False, 'bri': 1, 'hue': 13248, 'sat': 5, 'reachable': True}
Here is the value of data["state"]["on"] -->
False

Comment: I'm guessing that's true when you run it on your local machine, but apparently it isn't when you run it online?

Comment: Correct. (Apparently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataString` variable represented a dictionary (NOT a list) of values. It was necessary for me to use the [nestedGet()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156144/get-value-from-dictionary-given-a-list-of-nested-keys) function to determine the value of the "on" key.

`{"on":True} vs {"on":False})`

The final version of my fully-functional python script can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970085/aws-lambda-error-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-get).

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with @Grismar.  Catch the error:

```
try:
    if data["state"]["on"] == False:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":True}))
    elif data["state"]["on"] == True:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":False}))
except TypeError:
    dataString = str(Data).strip('[]')
    if dataString["state"]["on"] == False:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":True}))
    elif dataString["state"]["on"] == True:
        r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":False}))
```

or you could test `data` first:

```
if isinstance(data,str) == False
    dataString = str(data).strip('[]')
else:
    dataString = data

if dataString["state"]["on"] == False:
    r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":True}))
elif dataString["state"]["on"] == True:
    r = requests.put(f"{url}/state", json.dumps({"on":False}))
```